# Oracle SQL Query to extract data from yesterday 5:00:00 PM to today 5:00:00 AM

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, where-clause

I want to extract data on a daily basis from yesterday evening 5:00 PM to today morning 5:00 AM.  I have a column in the table that Timestamp format and stores both Time when the logs were created.

Altering session doesn't work for this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following `where` clause:

```
where mycol >= trunc(sysdate) - 7/24  -- yesterday at 5 PM
  and mycol <= trunc(sysdate) + 5/24  -- today at 5 AM
```

Side note: there is no `datetime` datatype in Oracle; datatype `date` stores a date *and* a time. This assumes that `mycol` is of that dataytpe.

On the other hand if you have a `timestamp`:

```
where mycol >= trunc(systimestamp) - interval '7' hour 
  and mycol <= trunc(systimestamp) + interval '5' hour
```

Comment: Sorry the column is just a timestamp and currently what I am using is mycol >='TO_TIMESTAMP ('11-09-2020 17:00:00.000000', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF').  I want to replace the plugging of date to sysdate-1 + 17/24

Comment: @NAD: ok, so you want to use the second `where` clause.